# Mongo: Move json string to a part of the document

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a mongo collection where documents have aprox the following structure:

```
item{
    data{"emailBody":
           "{\"uniqueKey\":\" this is a stringified json\"}"
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to use 'uniqueKey' as an indexed field, to make an "inner join" equivalant with items in a different collection.

I was thinking about running a loop on all the documents -> parsing the json -> Saving them as new property called "parsedEmailBody".

Is there a better way to handle stringified json in mongo?

Comment: "Is there a better way to handle stringified json in mongo?" - no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to loop through the collection, parse the field to JSON and update the document in the loop:

```
db.collection.find({ "item.data.emailBody": { "$type": 2 } })
  .snapshot().forEach(function(doc){
    parsedEmailBody = JSON.parse(doc.item.data.emailBody);
    printjson(parsedEmailBody);
    db.collection.updateOne(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "item.data.parsedEmailBody": parsedEmailBody } }
    );
});
```

For large collections, leverage the updates using the Bulk API:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({ "item.data.emailBody": { "$type": 2 } }).snapshot(),
    ops = [];

cursor.forEach(function(doc){ 
    var parsedEmailBody = JSON.parse(doc.item.data.emailBody);
    ops.push({ 
        "updateOne": {
            "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
            "update": { "$set": { "item.data.parsedEmailBody": parsedEmailBody } }
        }
    });

    if (ops.length === 500) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = [];
    }
});         

if (ops.length > 0) { db.collection.bulkWrite(ops); }
```

Comment: Looks beautiful, will be testing this now